# Is there a rigorous proof that $|G|=|\text{Ker}(f)||\text{Im}(f)|$, for some homomorphism $f\,:\,G\rightarrow G'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a rigorous proof that $|G|=|\text{Ker}(f)||\text{Im}(f)|$, for some homomorphism $f\,:\,G\rightarrow G'$? Can anyone provide such a proof with explanations?

Comment: do you know the 1st homomorphism theorem?

Comment: No I do not. I know the first isomorphism theorem, if that is related

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/First_Isomorphism_Theorem/Groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof in full detail.

You said in the comments that you know the first isomorphism theorem, which will make the proof quite simple. Let $f : G \to G'$ be the group homomorphism. The first isomorphism theorem tells us that $G / \ker(f)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{img}(f)$; hence $\lvert G / \ker f \rvert = \lvert \operatorname{img}(f) \rvert$. Next, we claim that $\lvert G \rvert = \lvert \ker f \rvert \lvert G / \ker f \rvert$. Once we can show this, we will have that $\lvert G \rvert = \lvert \ker f \rvert \lvert G / \ker f \rvert = \lvert \ker(f) \rvert \lvert \operatorname{img}(f) \rvert$, as desired! So here's the proof that $\lvert G \rvert = \lvert \ker f \rvert \lvert G / \ker f \rvert$:

*Proof*. Let $\pi : G \to G / \ker f$ be the canonical projection, and pick any splitting $\ell : G / \ker f \to G$ (all we're doing here is picking a representative of each coset), so that $\pi \circ \ell = \operatorname{id}_{G / \ker f}$. Now define $\varphi : G \to (\ker f) \times (G / \ker f)$ by $$\varphi(g) = (g^{-1} \ell(\pi(g)), \pi(g)).$$
$\varphi$ is well-defined because $$\pi(g^{-1}\ell(\pi(g))) = \pi(g)^{-1}\pi(\ell(\pi(g))) = \pi(g)^{-1} \operatorname{id}_{G / \ker f}(\pi(g)) = \pi(g)^{-1} \pi(g) = 1,$$
so $g^{-1} \ell(\pi(g)) \in \ker \pi = \ker f$ for all $g \in G$. Next, we will show that $\varphi$ is injective. Suppose $\varphi(x) = \varphi(y)$ for some $x, y \in G$. Since $\pi(x) = \pi(y)$, we know that $\ell(\pi(x)) = \ell(\pi(y))$. At the same time, we have $x^{-1} \ell(\pi(x)) = y^{-1} \ell(\pi(y))$, so we conclude that $x^{-1} = y^{-1}$, whence $x = y$. Finally, we need to show that $\varphi$ is surjective. Let $(a, b) \in (\ker f) \times (G / \ker f)$ be arbitrary, and let $x = \ell(b)a^{-1}$. Then
$$\pi(x) = \pi(\ell(b)a^{-1}) = \pi(\ell(b)) \pi(a)^{-1} \operatorname{id}_{G / \ker f}(b) 1^{-1} = b,$$
so
$$\varphi(x) = (x^{-1} \ell(\pi(x)), \pi(x)) = (a \ell(b)^{-1}\ell(b),b) = (a,b).$$
We have now shown that $\varphi$ is a bijection, so
$$\lvert G \rvert = \lvert (\ker f) \times (G / \ker f) \rvert = \lvert \ker f \rvert \lvert G / \ker f \rvert.$$

Answer (score 4):

$G$ acts on $Im(f)$ by $\theta_g(f(h))=f(gh)$. Then we can use the formula $|G|=|Stab(e)||Orbit(e)|$.

Comment: I have not yet learned Orbital Stabilizer.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f : G \to \mathrm{Im}f$. Is it by construction a surjective morphism. $\ker f$ is a subgroup of $G$. $f$ goes to the quotient to $\overline{f} : G/\ker f \to \mathrm{Im}f$. It is surjective and injective by construction, hence it's an isomorphism. So $|G/\ker f| = |\mathrm{Im} f|$. It is then easy to show that $|G / \ker f| = |G| / |\ker f|$

Comment: are you sure you mean minus?

Comment: Obviously it was a typo. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Dldier.

Comment: Technicality: this only works in the case that $G$ is finite! Otherwise $\lvert G \rvert / \lvert \ker f \rvert$ is impossible to define. Really you want to use the fact that $\lvert \ker f \rvert \lvert G / \ker f \rvert = \lvert G \rvert$, which says the same thing in spirit but is actually provable in generality.

Comment: I mean it is obvious in case of infinite cardinal

Comment: I agree, but only if you're already aware of the fact that this is a concern and are comfortable with infinite cardinals! Since it seems like the OP is towards the beginning of their math education, and they explicitly asked for rigorous proofs, I felt it was important to point out this detail.

Comment: ... I think I have to retract my agreement – I cannot think of a proof in the case that $G$ is infinite which does not go through the fact that $\lvert \ker f \rvert \lvert G / \ker f \rvert \geq \lvert G \rvert$. @DIdier_, do you have a proof in mind that actually avoids this step?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk as long as $a < b$, then the quotient $b/a$ is uniquely defined for any cardinals, even infinite ones. In that case, a proof of $|G / \ker f| = |G| / |\ker f|$ is the same as a proof of $|\ker f|\cdot|G / \ker f| = |G|.$ In the case that $|G| = |\ker f|$ is infinite, then just observe that $|\text{im}(f)|\cdot|\ker(f)| = |\text{im}(f)|\cdot|G| = \max{|\text{im}(f)|,|G|} = |G|$ since $|\text{im}(f)|\leq |G|$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, then the subgroup $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ of $G'$ is isomorphic to the factor group $G/\operatorname{Ker}(f)$. Therefore, the order of $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is the same as the order of $G/\operatorname{Ker}(f)$. The latter is also called the index of $\operatorname{Ker}(f)$ in $G$, and is the number of distinct cosets of $\operatorname{Ker}(f)$ in $G$. Since each coset has the same cardinality, that is the cardinality of $\operatorname{Ker}(f)$, you got that the order of the factor group is the quotient of the orders.

Comment: Technicality: this only works in the case that G is finite! Otherwise |G|/|kerf| is impossible to define. Really you want to use the fact that |kerf||G/kerf|=|G|, which says the same thing in spirit but is actually provable in generality.